# Cannot ChooseWhere to Install the Software and Configuring Storage: Installing oracle linux 8.3 on expired windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, oracle

I have created a bootable oracle linux 8.3 hard disk and restarted my windows machine by booting from the bootable hard disk which has oracle linux 8.3 iso.

It went well until this stage, where is it shows "No disks detected"

[image]

And cannot select any disk. How can i install oracle linux 8.3 on my machine. I am having an expired copy of Windows 7 currently, which i want to completely remove and have a single installation of oracle linux 8.3.

The ard disk does not show up to choose where to Install the Software and Configuring Storage. Also the custom option is disabled as shown below.

What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Don't know, but I would start by running a live cdrom/flash drive version of Linux without selecting Install and use it to inspect the disk drive on the computer and then possibly repartition it using gparted. While doing this, if something goes wrong, you should get more informative error messages. First see if the live distro sees your interal disk drive and if it looks like it's the expected size. If one doesn't work, try another live distro.